# Rails redirect registers in terminal but not on client

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Google geocode to let users create a new city. After registering the params and saving successfully, the cities controller redirects the user to the new_review_path (which is the page they were already on when they filled out the form).

When I look in terminal, everything seems to work just fine, and the new city is saved to the database.

```
Started POST "/cities" for ::1 at 2015-12-18 12:42:15 -0500
Processing by CitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Walla Walla", "latitude"=>"46.0645809", "longitude"=>"-118.3430209"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "cities" ("name", "latitude", "longitude", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Walla Walla"], ["latitude", 46.0646], ["longitude", -118.343], ["created_at", "2015-12-18 17:42:16.095349"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-18 17:42:16.095349"]]
   (8.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/reviews/new
Completed 302 Found in 116ms (ActiveRecord: 11.6ms)


Started GET "/reviews/new" for ::1 at 2015-12-18 12:42:16 -0500
Processing by ReviewsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  City Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities"
  Rendered reviews/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 128.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

But there's no change on the client. No flash message, no refresh. Is there something simple I'm overlooking here? Something to do with not using strong params maybe?

Here's my cities controller Create method:

```
  def create
    latitude = params[:latitude].to_f.round(4)
    longitude = params[:longitude].to_f.round(4)
    name = params[:name]
    city = City.new(name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    if city.save
      flash[:success] = "City created! Please refresh."
      redirect_to new_review_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Your city couldn't be created"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have turbo-links on? If so try uninstalling that gem and removing the remnants in app then restart your server and try again

Comment: Nope I don't have turbo-links so unfortunately that's not a solution.